# Struggling to find equivalent of "Cloakroom" in russian

Tags: перевод, лексикон

I believe in Russia, a cloakroom is known as Garderobe or раздевалка.

However, if I were to used it in a gallery - what should it be called?

Or what should I call a room where they come and pick up their stuff?

Thank you so much for your time..

Comment: According to https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/coat+check , гардероб is the same as coat check.

Answer (score 6):

Гардероб is the correct term. Раздевалка is a changing room, like at a swimming pool.

Comment: thank you! can Гардероб be used as a "Pickup your stuff/belonging" area? thanks

Comment: @Kit Sithinun for your purposes **гардероб** is OK, in раздевалка people completely change their outfit, dress down to their underwear or almost so (except in schools), not just take off and leave the outer clothing... another maybe a more fitting term is **гардеробная**, because in a **гардероб** there's usually a person who accepts and hands out clothing, what you describe seems like a self service room with lockers or the like

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Thank you - its not self-service - there will be someone who hand you the item. Its pretty much a gallery and someone will hand you your stuff

Comment: @Kit Sithinun i see, then гардероб

Comment: Yep, like the one in theatres or nightclubs where you can hand in your coat or bag for storage, sometimes for a fee.

Comment: Can this be used instead: "Место для посадки пассажиров"